# Pass multiple jQuery element selectors to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-selectors

myFunc() is bound to the document scroll so it will be called a lot. I want to store the HTML selections in a var and pass them to the function. When I run my example below I get the console error `Unable to get value of the property 'css': object is null or undefined`.

```
var a1 = $('#a1');
var a2 = $('#a2');

$(document).bind("scroll", function() {
  setTimeout(myFunc, 1000, a1, a2);
}

function myFunc(a1, a2) {
  a1.css('color', 'blue');
  a2.css('font-weight', 'bold');
}
```

How do I pass multiple jQuery selectors, stored in a variables, to a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).bind("scroll", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
      myFunc(a1, a2);
    },1000);
}); // close );

function myFunc(a1, a2) {
  a1.css('color', 'blue');
  a2.css('font-weight', 'bold');
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't OP's code do the same thing (except in old browsers) ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$(document).bind("scroll", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myFunc(a1, a2);
    }, 1000);
}); // and close properly your function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `a1` and `a2` variables may be set before the elements with `#a1` and `#a2` exist on the page (especially if this isn't wrapped in an onload/ready handler and the script is in the header). I would set this up like so, to ensure that `#a1` and `#a2` exists at the time of the scroll event.

```
var a1 = undefined;
var a2 = undefined;

$(document).bind("scroll", function() {
  if(typeof(a1) === "undefined") { a1 = $("#a1");} //will only reset a1 if undefined
  if(typeof(a2) === "undefined") {a2 = $("#a2");}

  setTimeout(function(){myFunc(a1,a2)}, 1000);
}); //don't forget your ')'

function myFunc(a1, a2) { 
  a1.css('color', 'blue');
  a2.css('font-weight', 'bold');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also store your elements inside an array:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ititud/1/edit)**

```
var a1 = ['#a1','#a2'];

$(document).bind("scroll", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myFunc(a1);
    }, 1000);
});

function myFunc(el) {
  $(el[0]).css('color', 'blue');
  $(el[1]).css('font-weight', 'bold');
}
```